# State tag suggestion

Tags: discussion, tags

We need tags for all 50 states, and probably the territories.  For example there is no Washington or Washington DC tag, but there is California.

Comment: Now, the question really is - How do we proceed? New questions only (fine) or a methodical updated tag for existing questions, too?

Answer (score 2):

If I agreed, I'd suggest that we add tags as needed.

I glanced at the California tagged questions, and it would seem that it happens the member lives there, but the question applies to all state with a state tax. Do those questions really need the tag?

To the comment regarding Washington question -
For the fact that WA has no income tax, does a Washington tag add value? Any state combo including a no-tax state would have the same result. I have no issue with state tags, I wouldn't delete any, I just don't see the widespread need.

Since adding a tag to a question would flood the screen and push new questions down, I'd strongly suggest adding to new questions as they are asked, and only editing old questions a few at a time.

EDIT -

[image]

The recent Washington question has 5 tags. Which one do we drop from the question in favor of Washington?

Comment: A guy asked a question about Washington state yesterday.

Comment: Link? I searched, and don't see it.

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66491/how-much-does-a-landlord-pay-in-taxes

Comment: Agreed.  We shouldn't add tags until there are questions.  In fact, I think I remember reading that tags with no questions get purged after a while.

Comment: Right. Just pointing out that there are 86 questions that show for a Washington search, and more with WA. If we do this at once, we push new questions to page 3 pretty quick. That was my point. Add the tag when new question come up. And edit tags in, but 1-3 at a time.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I agree with [that point, too](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/are-minor-grammar-edits-desirable/2190#comment5211_2190).

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts:

1. [We can't create a tag without there being a question about it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124712/232449) So until there is a question specific to [Montana](https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=montana+is%3Aquestion), we can't create a [montana](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/montana) tag.
2. In my opinion, we should only use a state tag in questions that truly involve something unique to that state.  I think we need to be more picky about when to include the state tag then we are with including the [united-states](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag.  The obvious use of the state tag is questions about the state income tax of a particular state, but there may be other types of questions that involve the uniqueness of a particular state.  A mere mention of the state by itself does not warrant the use of the state tag, in my opinion.

Taking an example from my home state of Wisconsin: I created the [wisconsin](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wisconsin) tag when [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/59047/10997) was asked.  The subject of the question is about a quirk of TurboTax's Wisconsin state income tax software and is totally unique to Wisconsin; the question should have the state tag.  Later, when [this question (How do I decide where to register a car when I plan to move soon?)](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/65842/10997) was asked, I added the [wisconsin](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wisconsin) tag and also created the [minnesota](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minnesota) tag.  In hindsight, I don't think this second question warrants any state tags: the question and answers could be about any state.

To be clear, the "register a car" question should indeed mention the states' names in the question text itself, because it *could* be important information.  But judging by the answers so far, it seems that it is not important information, and doesn't need the state tags.  If an answer appears in the future that reveals something unique about Wisconsin or Minnesota that makes a difference, perhaps the tags would be more important then and could be added at that time.

Adding state tags to old questions is okay, as long as the question (and answers) are really unique to the state.  Also, I agree with [@JoeTaxpayer's answer](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/state-tag-suggestion/2316#2316) that old questions should only be edited a few at a time, so as not to flood the front page with old questions and push the current questions out.

Comment: Agreed we can't and shouldn't create en-mass tags. We still do not have tags for all country as example. We should create a specific tag as post facto only if there are likely to be quite a few questions about the same.

Comment: I agree, although in some cases the asker may not know whether the issue is state-specific or not.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes.  With some questions, we might not know for sure if a state tag is appropriate until the answer is known.